# Переход между окнами - Android

Tags: java, android

юзая AndroidStudio воздник вопрос...
при создании нового проекта в андройде при указании формы BlankActivity выстраивается код из
activity_main.xml
и
content_main.xml

причем 2ое вложенно в 1ое, т.е. грузиться основной экран в котором найдя строку

```
 <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

грузиться 2ой экран
по сути ограничивая написание меню в activity_main
но в моем источнике ессено не написано как это можно использовать

собственно возник вопрос: можно ли программно менять вложенный layout дабы сократить однообразное написание главного окна для каждого контента?

ну ессено при нажатии на какую-либо кнопку в коде
через

"кот" утрирован

```
        switch(event.getAction()){  
               case event.ACTION_LEFT:
                    вызов <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
                    break;
                case event.ACTION_RIGHT:
                     вызов <include layout="@layout/content_main2" />
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не поняли его, он спрашивает, как программно подключить макет. Когда АС генерирует проект, то в нем бывает как правило activity_main и content_main, где  в activity_main прописывается app_bar, toolbar, и под ними подключается макет content_main, путем include layout="@layout/content_main", и вопрос заключается в том, как этот include layout="@layout/content_main" сделать программно, а не в разметке? В общем автор вопроса, глянь тут, там пример в RecyclerView

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363555/programmatically-include-layout-in-android-replicating-the-include-tag

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы можете создавать разные разметки под разные экраны и хранить их в отдельных файлах.
2. В разметке да, можно использовать `include`
3. В коде, во время исполнения, вы можете загрузить разметку из файла `xml` и загрузить её в другую разметку. Также можно и удалить часть текущей.

Для последнего пункта вам понадобятся `LayoutInflater` и поиск `View` элементов разметки методом `findViewById`, в коий передаётся `id` элемента разметки, коий в этом элементе, в самой разметке, указан.

Comment: можно пример для 3го варианта на подобии: `setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) { switch(v.getId()) { case R.id.buttonOne: //тут вызов FirstActivity break; case R.id.buttonTwo: //тут вызов SecondActivity break; } } });`

Comment: @ЯрославПрохоров, вам надо пример запуска активити?...

Comment: не, вопрос немного может не поняли

Comment: если я вызову активити Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
      startActivity(intent); откроется второе активити и придется рисовать все заного, меня интересует как сделать чтобы имея главную активити где все меню и т.д. можно было переключать только дочерние, а родительское оставалось тем же, тем самым уменьшить повторяющейся код

Comment: @ЯрославПрохоров, кажется я действительно вас не понимаю. Вы интересуетесь можно ли вторую активити унаследовать от класса первой?..

Comment: создав проэкт в студии - иметься Main_activity (в ней прорисовано меню и т.п.) в нем есть строка `<include layout="@layout/content_main" />` которая загружает 2ую активити (где основное окно приложения), я хочу узнать можно ли программно переключать контент_мейн1, 2, 3, по кнопкам в мейн_активити не рисуя больше Мейн_активити для каждого контента, т.е. 1 Main_activity которое переключает @layout/content_main2, @layout/content_main3 и т.д.

Comment: @ЯрославПрохоров, в include загружается не активити, а разметка оной. Обычно разные разметки в одной активити отображают через фрагменты. Но, в принципе, вы можете просто получить View по его ID, удалить и вместо него загрузить другой, да. Но лучше через фрагменты.

Comment: т.е. нажав кнопку скрывать предыдущий фрагмент, показывая нужный?

Comment: @ЯрославПрохоров, да, идея такая.

Comment: я думал если указан для примера `@layout/content_main` можно их как то переключать

Comment: @ЯрославПрохоров, примеры не всегда хорошему и правильному учат)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, для фрагментов доступен также весь функционал как для активити и отличий в данном случае не будет т.к. фрагмент также реализуется отдельным xml файлом?

Comment: @ЯрославПрохоров, отличий мелких много, но в целом фрагмент это просто несколько урезанная активити со всоей разметкой и своим жизненным циклом, позволяющий отображать разный контент без создания новой активити.

Comment: больше интересует не будут ли накладываться слушатели кнопок и т.д. Например у основного окна activity_main слушатель кнопок, и у Fragment_first слушатель кнопок, по сути 2 слушателя на 1ом экране

Comment: @ЯрославПрохоров, слушатели назначаются на конкретные View|menu по их ID. Засим мне сложно вообразить возможный конфликт.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде, чем пытаться подменять разметки в активити, вам следует прочитать [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513812/177345).

В данном шаблоне используется вложенная разметка (content_main.xml) исключительно в целях разделить вид на экране между служебными элементами (тулбар, меню и тп.) и собственно контентом прикладного программиста, в целях сделать эту разметку более "чистой" для этого программиста. При этом фактически мы имеем одну разметку, разбитую на два отдельных файла, они как бы не отделимы и так же неразрывно связаны с прикрепленной к ней активити, как и разметка без `<include>`. Ни о какой возможности подмены в такой структуре не стоит даже задумываться - это приведет только к проблемам.

Так же этот шаблон видимо для начинающих, чтобы упростить им написание приложения. В реальном проекте такой подход не имеет никаких особых преимуществ и вообще какого то практического смысла (я не встречал в исходниках реальных open source программ такой структуры разметки ни разу).

Для исключения дублирования кода можно использовать фрагменты или наследование от "базовой" активити, как в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/592019/177345), в зависимости от решаемых задач. Про использование "базовой" активити очень хорошо рассказывается в книге Б.Харди "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" 2016г. (как и множество других не менее интересных вещей).

Впрочем, вы вполне можете подменять какие-то статические разметки, к которым не происходит обращения из кода активити и они никак не реагируют на действия пользователя и содержащиеся в ней виджеты никак не изменяются в процессе работы приложения.

PS: я бы рекомендовал вообще не использовать готовые шаблоны студии с какими то реализациями, все они страдают избыточностью и ненужной "универсальностью"