# Выводить текст в несколько layout с одного MainActivity

Tags: java, android

Проблема в AndroidStudio. Есть несколько `Layout`, есть `MainActivity.java`. Переключаюсь между ними через `setContentView`, через `onClick()` в `Layout`. Переключатся отлично! Такие команды, как `finish()` и `SystemOutPrintln()` тоже прекрасно запускаются. Но при подаче команды `setText()` всё крашится.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {
TextView tvOut;
Button btnStart;

public void onClickzadvopr(View v)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.shar);
}
public void onClickreshenie(View v)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.monetka);
}
public void onClickSigrkosti(View v)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.kosti);
}
public void onClickuznvolzvzd(View v)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.goroskop);
}
public void onClickNazad(View v)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
//public void onClickStart(View v) {tvOut.setText("Нажата кнопка ОК");  // Вот если эту строку сделать активной — всё крашится при нажатии на кнопку! 



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOut);



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

Глюк проявляется только при нажатии на кнопку. Пробовал другие способы вывода текста (создавал обработчик, заполнял метод `onClick()`, присваивал обработчик кнопке), тогда крашилось сразу же, как запускалось.

Если пробовать метод через `switch(getId)` и `case` — тоже крашится при нажатии кнопки.  Мне говорили, что надо создавать другие активити через `Intent` Но неужели нельзя просто вывести текст из одного `MainActivity.java` в несколько разных `Layout`?
Ведь по той же самой команде `onClick()` переключение и остальные команды прекрасно работают, почему не работает `setText()`? А вот как выглядит-то активити-кнопка, из которого крашит всё:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Назад!"
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="onClickNazad"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="шар"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button

    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="start">

</Button>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvOut"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="TextView">
</TextView>
```

Comment: Причем здесь проблема в Android Studio? вы же не думаете, что в том же Eclipse что то будет работать по другому .. Менять разметку в одном активити - худшая практика из тех, что можно придумать. Для новой разметки используйте новую активити (или фрагмент)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Подмена разметки активити через метод `setContentView()` худшая из возможных практик в разработке Android, которая не может рассматриваться в качестве рабочего решения, поэтому лучшим решением вашего вопроса будет оставить эти бесполезные попытки и не пытаться решить вашу задачу таким неправильным способом.

Возможно сейчас вам кажется, что это замечательное решение и как остальные до него за 15 лет не додумались, но продолжая работать в этом направлении вы в один прекрасный момент поймете, почему другие так не делают и останется только пожалеть напрасно потраченного времени. Причина же в том, что поскольку активити - контроллер виджетов на разметке, то ее подмена делает управление этой разметки хаосом, трудно контроллируемым и абсурдным по реализуемой логике.

Правило простое: одна разметка - одно активити, либо одна хост-активити, несколько фрагментов. Смысл в том, что у каждой разметки должен быть собственный контроллер, так как они не разделимы: вид на экране (разметка) и его управление (активити)

**UPD**

Конкретно в вашем случае причина ваших проблем кроется скорее всего в том, что в той разметке, еа которую вы подменяете первоначальную никакого виджета tvOut не существует или что еще хуже - это другой ID с тем же именем, что и в первоначальной разметке. Не смотря на то, что имена их одинаковы - это разные виджеты и вы обращаетесь к тому виджету, разметка которого уже не существует, а заменена на другую. Стоит заметить, что это одна из простейших проблем, которые вас ждут практикуя этот нелепый подход - дальше будет только намного хуже.

Comment: Благодарю, будем работать через intent. А такие вещи как переключение страничек друг на друга - тоже лучше не использовать setContentView()? Его вообще лучше никогда не использовать?

Comment: @Dmitrii разметка через `setContentView()` должна быть установлена однажды в начале метода `onCreate()` и больше не меняться в текущей активити. Новая разметка - новая активити, они как одно целое, вид на экране(разметка) и его управление (активити)