# Телефонная кнопка назад

Tags: java, android, xml

Когда нажимаю на кнопку назад на телефоне приложение закрывается. Как сделать так, чтобы приложение не закрывалось, а переходило на предыдущий `contentView`.

**Например:**
Сцена на которой я сейчас называется "Урок1", когда я нажму на кнопку назад я выйду из приложения, а я хочу чтобы оно перешло на другую сцену "Уроки".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно, будет достаточно переопределить метод

```
public void onBackPressed()
```

В котором сделать изменение сцены

Answer (score 1):

Переходить на другую "сцену" надо через вызов новой активити (или фрагмента) с нужной разметкой, а не подменой разметки методом `setContentView()` в одной и той же активити, тогда и кнопка назад будет работать правильно и [проблем у вас не будет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513812/177345).