# Ошибка при возвращении на layout с google maps

Tags: android

Создал приложение, в котором реализован фрагмент с Google maps

Код в Main_Activity

```
private void createMapView() {
    /**
     * Catch the null pointer exception that
     * may be thrown when initialising the map
     */
    try {
        if (null == googleMap) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.mapView)).getMap();

            /**
             * If the map is still null after attempted initialisation,
             * show an error to the user
             */
            if (null == googleMap) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error creating map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException exception){}
}
```

Код в XML

```
  <fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mapView" />
```

При запуске программы всё работает, но когда перехожу на другой layout, а потом обратно на layout с картой, приложение закрывается в от такими ошибками:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #114: Error inflating class fragment
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #114: Duplicate id 0x7f0d0082, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
```

При этом ошибки выделенные синим указывают на строку, включающую отображение layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Кто-нибудь знает, как справиться?

*Дополнение:
Метод createMepView() вызывается в 2 местах: в самом начале

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvEnabledGPS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEnabledGPS);
    tvLocationGPS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocationGPS);
    tvEnabledNet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEnabledNet);
    tvLocationNet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocationNet);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    createMapView();
    addMarker();
}
```

и при возвращении на этот layout

```
public void bgot (View view){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvEnabledGPS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEnabledGPS);
    tvLocationGPS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocationGPS);
    tvEnabledNet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEnabledNet);
    tvLocationNet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocationNet);
    Plt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Plt);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    createMapView();
    addMarker();
```

Comment: покажите код Активити, в которой у вас реализован вызов метода createMapView()

Comment: Добавил в вопрос коды, где вызывается createMapView()

Comment: а что значит при возвращении на layout? setContentView должен вызываться только в одном месте. и только в onCreate

Comment: Вместо создания нескольких Активити, я не первый раз делаю переключение между разными layout. Но только с картой произошла такая ошибка

Comment: то, что вы делаете с `setContentView()` - [грубейшее нарушение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513812/177345) архитектуры приложения и решать этот вопрос не имеет смысла, так как ошибка уже в том, что используются изначально неприемлемые практики. Делайте, как положено - одна активити(фрагмент) - один лэйаут и все будет работать, иначе самостоятельно разбирайтесь с таким ужасным костылем. Такой практике вообще не место на SoF.ru

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, дело в том, что MapView сохраняется во время переключения назад и вперед между layout'ами, и такое поведение приводит к созданию дубликата MapView, который будет создаваться при каждом новом MapFragment с тем же ID.

Решение состоит в том, чтобы вручную удалить `MapFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    MapFragment f = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                                         .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
    if (f != null) 
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
}
```