# Как узнать имя текущего layout у Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Здравствуйте.
К сожалению, поиск  не дал результатов.
Существует активити, где описан текущий layout-файл.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_Main);
```

В рамках приложения layout-файл меняется несколько раз. Каким образом я могу  узнать имя  текущего layout-файла у активити?

Comment: Если у вас несколько раз меняется `layout` у `Activity`, значит у вас неправильная архитектура. Одна `Activity` - один `layout`.

Comment: Поиск не дал результатов потому, что то, что вы делаете [несовместимо с архитектурой](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513812/177345) андроид-приложения. Вам нужно как можно быстрее отказаться от этого ущербного подхода и не тратить время на поиски заведомо неприемлемого решения. Потом все равно будете переделывать.

Comment: Товарищи, вопрос был не в том, как архитектуру лучше сделать, а как узнать имя ресурса

Comment: @P.Ilyin -- Возможно я  неверно сформулировал вопрос) Но Вы единственный, кто его верно прочитал)

Comment: @P.Ilyin никто и не пишет ОТВЕТ, что неправильная архитектура и уходи. НО! о том, что человек делает себе очень плохо с таким решением предупредить надо.

Comment: просто записывайте id в переменную каждый раз, когда делаете `setContentView()`

Answer (score 1):

Можно хранить id текущей разметки в `int` переменной.

Зная id разметки, можно добыть её имя внутри активити вот так:

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resid);
```

или

```
getResources().getResourceName(int resid);
```