# Обновление макета фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, fragment-transaction, fragment-manager

Подскажите, у меня фрагмент наполняется в onCreateView относительно данных, и есть ситуация в которой данные изменились, но не изменилось их отображение, как мне обновить фрагмент, или просто заменить макет? Фактически нужно опять вызвать onCreateView

Comment: Прежде чем продолжать в этом направлении, рекомендую ознакомиться с [этим ответом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513812/177345). Все там сказанное в той же степени относится и к фрагменту.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вообщем я решил проблему, увидев подобный вопрос, я просто вызываю `detach`, и потом `attach`, и происходит обновление моего макета, не знаю на счет качества этого решения. Но оно работает

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите наполнение фрагмента данными в отдельный метод `void render(Model model)` и вызывайте этот метод в onCreateView, либо при изменении модели

Comment: Была такая мысль, но как мне менять макет ? я его не могу явно указать, я лишь возвращаю его как View в onCreateView