# Два активити одном java-файле

Tags: java, android

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
```

Могу ли я так, в одном java-файле два активити прописать? Т.е надо сделать так, чтобы когда загружался java-файл, он загрузил два активити - один спереди, а второй сзади. Первый должен перекрывать полностью второй.

Или эту задачу можно решить только добавив второй java-файл?

Comment: Прочитайте [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513812/177345). Помимо грубейшего нарушения архитектуры приложения, такое действие будет абсолютно бессмысленным, так как (из вашего описания задачи) разметка под другой разметкой будет невидима на экране и никаким образом проявлять себя не будет. Так же, вашем вопросе некоторое непонимание происходящего . Так, активити это класс-контроллер разметки на экране, а не сама разметка, метод setContentView() устанавливает разметку для активити и новый вызов заменит одну разметку на другую. Уточните вопрос, какую именно проблему вам нужно решить.

Comment: Тут я неправильно описал проблему - не два layout-а, а два активити.

Comment: Есть два активити - первая передняя и вторая сзади. На втором некоторые функций запускаются взависимости от размера  вью, которые на нем расположены. И запускаются они во время onCreate() Если я сразу загружу вторую, то посыпятся ошибки так как все параметры вью во время onCreate равны нулю. Поэтому загружаю первый активити. На нем есть кнопка ЗАПУСК, которая запускает второй активити.

Comment: Проблема по прежнему не ясна. Сделайте дополнения в вопрос, (кнопка "править" под вопросом), в котором как можно понятней опишите, что именно вам необходимо сделать. Какие именно параметры устанавливаются в первой, как влияют на вторую, лучше всего с кодом.

Answer (score 0):

В одной активности не допускается множественный вызов `setContentView()`.

Поместите обе разметки в `FrameLayout` и показываете ее в `setContentView`. Та, что будет вторая перекроет первую, но вы сможете работать с обеими

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        <!-- нижняя разметка -->
    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         <!-- верхняя разметка -->
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**ЗАМОРОЖЕНО ДО ВЫЯВЛЕНИЯ СУТИ ВОПРОСА**

Comment: Думаю в вопросе не об этом речь, а о том, что на первом экране устанавливаются какие то параметры размера View, которые потом влияют на размеры View второго экрана. Задавший вопрос смутно ориентируется в разнице между разметкой и активити, но речь идет, думаю, о двух активити. Пока проблема в вопросе не прояснится, лучше ничего не отвечать. а то все еще больше запутается.