# Как переключать макет .xml в приложении?

Tags: java, view, android-xml, app

Возможно ли реализовать такое:

У меня есть одно активити, и оно использует макет **activity_main.xml**, могу ли я по кнопке например сделать так, чтоб оно перезагрузилось с макетом activity_main_2.xml. Просто хочу в приложении сделать два варианта просмотра информации (списком и в 3 колонки). Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы)))

Comment: варианты списком и в три колонки решаются не подменой разметки, а переназначением LayoutManager для RecyclerView. Вообще, подменить разметку можно, если виджеты на обеих разметках, к которым обращаются из кода, имеют одинаковые ID и назначение, иначе вас ждет [множество проблем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513812/177345).

Comment: На будущее - вопрос нужно задавать по самой проблеме, а не по вашему [неправильному] способу ее решения, то есть в вашем случае:"как сделать отображение списком и в три колонки", а не "как заменить разметку", к вопросу необходимо добавить всю полезную информацию по проблеме, код вызывающий эту проблему и проч. - экстрасенсы сюда заходят очень редко. Этот вопрос исправлять **не нужно**, так как на него уже дан ответ. Теперь вы можете задать другой вопрос и подойти к его оформлению более ответственно.

Answer (score 1):

Изменить макет можно ([хотя так строго не рекомендуется делать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513812/177345)), для этого в обработчике клика нужно ещё раз вызвать метод `setContentView`.

То есть в `onCreate` вызываешь `setContenView(R.layout.activity_main)`, а в обработчике клика вызываешь `setContenView(R.layout.activity_main_2)`.

Comment: В общем случае такие действия [строго не рекомендуются](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513812/177345) и возможны только при изменении взаимрасположения  одних и тех же виджетов на обоих разметках или при статических виджетах (к которым не обращаются из кода)

Comment: я так пробывал уже., но у меня по мимо этого еще стоит значение setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)); в методе OnCreate . которое не дает нужных изменений в результате

Comment: можно его тоже менять через обработчик клика? вместо 4-х колонок вызывать при клике 2 например ??

Comment: или можно проще как-то ? Вобще возможно ли "перезагрузить" активити, в котором будет не 4 а две колонки ?

Comment: @Антон Все, что вы сейчас спрашиваете в этих комментариях, никак не относится к вашему вопросу (как переключать макет), решение которого получено в этом ответе. Если у вас другие проблемы, которые вы не можете решить самостоятельно, задайте другой вопрос. Дело в том, что этот ресурс не персональная бесплатная помощь нуждающимся, с личными консультациями, а Q&A, который имеет [свои правила](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) и не предусматривает каких то дискуссий, обсуждений и подобных "а можно тогда по другому .." . Задали вопрос - получили ответ на **вопрос**