# Проблема с кнопкой

Tags: java, android

При нажатии на кнопку выкидывает из приложения.С 32 по 40 строку.
А именно: `

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Eng_lvl.this, Eng_learn.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });`

    package com.daylang.daylang;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class Eng_lvl extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int curTime;
    private int someValue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loadscreen);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
//noinspection WrongConstant
        if (calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1) {
            setContentView(R.layout.eng_lvl);
        }
        else if (calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) == Calendar.WEDNESDAY) {
            setContentView(R.layout.eng_learn);
        }
        StartAnimations();
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Eng_lvl.this, Eng_learn.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
    private void StartAnimations() {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytrans);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stars);
        iv.clearAnimation();
        iv.startAnimation(anim);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytrans2);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView l = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stars2);
        l.clearAnimation();
        l.startAnimation(anim);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytrans5);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView B = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stars3);
        B.clearAnimation();
        B.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте логи ошибки (в т.ч. тип ошибки) и укажите однозначно на какой строке падает. Скорее всего у вас NPE и просто в разметке нет кнопки с указанным ID, т.е. у вас просто опечатка.

Comment: Прежде, чем подменять разметки в активити, вам необходимо знать, что [работать все это вряд ли будет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513812/177345)

Comment: `calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) == Calendar.WEDNESDAY` сравнивать число в месяце со средой, занятие немного странное.

Comment: @eugeneek и в правду...Про это я не подумал,но если я пишу  else if (calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) == 2) то цифра 2 подчёркивается красным.

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум поставьте проверку на null, особенно если это не (Button).