# android Диалоговое окно

Tags: android

Проблема в том, что в приложении будет несколько диологовых окон, и я хочу вынести их в отдельный класс. Но при этом я ловлю nullpointerexception при использовании setContentView(). Я только начинаю знакомство с android studio и думаю что должен же быть способ вызова setContentView() из других классов.
Заранее благодарю.

```
    public class Dialogs extends MainActivity {

public void newLanguageDialog(Context context , final View view){
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setView(R.layout.dialog_newblock);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("111");
    builder.setMessage("222");
    final EditText input = new EditText(context);
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main_one);
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            String a = input.getText().toString();
            if (a != null && a.length() > 0) {
                MainActivity.s = a;
                //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                dialog.cancel();
            } else {
                setContentView(R.layout.main_one);
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Пока придумал сделать так: передать в метод экземпляр класса Main и вызвать через него новый метод в классе Main. Новый метод:public void ssetContent(int value)
    {
        setContentView(value);
    }

Comment: Прежде чем продолжать в этом направлении, вам стоит [прочитать это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513812/177345) и отказаться от такой идеи, пока не потрачено слишком много сил на негодное решение

Answer (score 1):

У Вас тут накручено, невозможно понять, какой цели Вы пытаетесь достичь, для билдера два раза вызвается метод setView, а setContentView вызывается у класса активити. Что касается editText, то его правильнее всего было бы сделать edit text внутри dialog_newblock.xml, назначить ему id (например edit_text) и сделать примерно так

```
public class Dialogs extends MainActivity {

    public void newLanguageDialog(Context context , final View view){
        View view  = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_newblock);
        EditText input = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle("111");
        builder.setMessage("222");
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // do smth
                // dialog.cancel(); - не надо вызывать, вызовется само
            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                String a = input.getText().toString();
                if (a.length() > 0) {
                    MainActivity.s = a; 
                    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    // dialog.cancel();
                } else {
                    // setContentView(R.layout.main_one);
                    // dialog.cancel();
                }
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

В какой момент вызывается диалог? И в какой момент вызывается setContentView? Если честно мне кажется странной идея менять содержимое активити по нажатию на кнопку (я ни разу этого не делал, не уверен даже, что это сработает), лучше сделать контейнером активити и внутри нее менять фрагменты

И по вашему вопросу не совсем понятно, чего вы пытаетесь добиться.

UPDATED:

Создал проект и попробовал - сработало )) Очень мило. Однако попробую вас убедить - это плохая практика, хендлить несколько разметок в одной активити. ПРоект имеет свойство разрастаться, и для каждой разметки вам придется объединять привязку view в отдельную логику, которая будет находиться в рамках одного класса (Вашей активити). В тоге это разрастется на много сотен и тысяч мало управляемых строк кода. Правильнее делать несколько активити, или одну активити с контейнером (FrameLayout, например) куда добавлять разные фрагменты, в которые будет икасулирована логика каждой отдельной страницы. И нет ничего страшного втом, что классов у вас будет несколько, а не один. И более того, если идти дальше, то логику представления вообще лучше отделять от бизнес логики, но это уже узнаете потом, когда познакомитесь с архитектурными паттернами или такой замечательной штукой, как Android Data Binding.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Стыдно признаться но я пока ещё не понял как создавать отдельные джава классы для каждой активности и взаимодействовать между ними. Это моё первое приложение для андроид. И я был бы очень признателен если бы вы мне посоветовали хорошие курсы по android на русском языке и с задачами. Сейчас я изучаю джаву на ДжаваРаш.

Comment: Диалог вызывается из МаинАктивити при переходе к другой активити и предлагается пользователю ввести некую строку для дальнейшего её использования в приложении. И если пользователь нажимает cancel или не ввел ни одного символа, то он должен снова попадать в МайнАктивити, а если ввёл, то переходить к новой активити.   П.С. В данном коментарии под активити я имею ввиду экран приложения. Извените, пока путаюсь в терминах.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛищенко В таком случае создаем отдельный класс активити, наследуем его от Activity, в onCreate через setContentView подсовываем вторую разметку. Добавляем активити в манифест (интент фильтр не нужен). После чего в диалоге по клику на клавиши убираем все кроме if (input.getText().length() > 0) { Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class); context.startActivity(intent); } по нажатию на ок. Наверное есть много ресурсов, я в свое время пользовался  startandroid и developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android, надеюсь админы не посчитают это рекламой :) Удачи

Comment: Все, что я писал написано на коленке, но вы потом сами для себя поймете как надо и как лучше. С фрагментами все тоже довольно просто, но у них есть свои особенности, поэтому к ним лучше обращайтесь позже

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛищенко А ещё очень хорошо понимать что нужно, разделять задачу на мелкие составляющие и гуглить. "how to create dialog", "how to add action to dialog", "how to open another activity". Такие мелкие вещи очень легко ищутся и помогают лучше всяких учебников

Comment: Спасибо большое ещё раз! ))) Пойду читать что такое манифест и интент)