# Привязка кнопок к layout через intent?

Tags: android

Вопрос новичка в андроиде. Начал изучать интенты: хочу привязать 3 кнопки к 3 layout, чтобы во второй активити было видно какую кнопку нажали и вызывался соответствующий layout. Так вообще делают? И как это сделать правильно через intent?

Activity_1.java:

```
public void onClick(View v){  
switch (v.getId()){  
  case R.id.button_1: {  
   Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),Activity_2.class);  
   intent.putExtra("key","b1");  
   startActivity(intent);  
   break;  
} 
case R.id.button_2: {  
   Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),Activity_2.class);  
   intent.putExtra("key","b2");  
   startActivity(intent);  
   break;  
}
case R.id.button_3: {  
   Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),Activity_2.class);  
   intent.putExtra("key","b3");  
   startActivity(intent);  
   break;  
}
```

Activity_2.java:

```
@Override  
  protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
  super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);  

  String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");  
  if (data == "b1")  
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_number1);  
  else if (data == "b2")  
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_number2);  
  else  
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_number3);  
}
```

Comment: Прежде, чем продолжать, вы должны прочитать [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513812/177345) и еще раз хорошо подумать

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо за ссылку. Я правильно понимаю, что такое решение в реальной практике не используется? Т.е. если много layout, то лучше реализовывать через фрагменты?

Comment: вы можете попытаться, но очень скоро поймете, что оно не просто не используется, а абсолютно не рабочее, если вы как то планируете взаимодействовать с интерфейсом.

Comment: @pavlofff Я хочу сразу делать как надо. В данном конкретном случае правильно будет создать 3 Activity для каждой разметки?

Comment: Если каждый экран будет отображать различные виджеты (разные компоновки экранов), то да: 3 активити или 1 активити с 3-мя фрагментами

Answer (score 0):

В целом все правильно. Но можно упростить код.

Добавьте в `Activity_2.java` статический метод `start(String key)`. Он запускает `Activity_2` с дополнением `key` (записывает в интент строковый аргумент `key`).

```
public static void start(Context context, String key) {
    Intent starter = new Intent(context, Activity_2.class);
    starter.putExtra("KEY", key);
    context.startActivity(starter);
  }
```

И в `Activity_1.java` примет такой вид:

```
public void onClick(View v){  
switch (v.getId()){  
  case R.id.button_1: {  
   Activity_2.start(Activity_1.this, "b1");
   break;  
} 
case R.id.button_2: {  
   Activity_2.start(Activity_1.this, "b2");  
   break;  
}
case R.id.button_3: {  
   Activity_2.start(Activity_1.this, "b3");  
   break;  
}
```

Comment: не могу понять почему вызывается только (R.layout.activity_number3)?

Comment: @Mr_FFFFFF, [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417405/11515)

Comment: @woesss спасибо )