# Изменение внешнего вида фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Можно ли изменить внешний вид фрагмента (установить другой `View`) во время его работы или это возможно только в методе `onCreateView()`?

Другими словами можно ли использовать метод `setContentView()` где-то ещё?

Comment: у фрагмента нет метода setContentView(), это метод активности. Смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513812/177345) о подмене разметки.

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо! Теперь понял, что к чему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от того, что Вам нужно изменить! Если что-то спрятать/показать/покрасить - то работайте с этим же фрагментом. Если же должна меняться еще и логика поведения, то будет уместно использовать дочерние фрагменты, которыми Вы можете "жонглировать" по необходимости.

Comment: Уточнил вопрос.