# Как правильно использовать flavor с разными макетами?

Tags: android

Предположим есть проект, который загружает определенный список.

Требование загрузить список по `flavor` в:

1)  `listview`

2)  `gridview`

n)  `custom view`

Какой правильный подход в этом случае использовать, т.к. элементы представление меняются в зависимости от выбора `flavor`?

Comment: не совсем понятно для чего вам это, но вообще механизм flavors - это для вариантов сборки приложения, например демо-версия и полная или платная и бесплатная, а не то, чтобы какие то макеты переключать, что бы это не значило

Comment: Это зависит от полного кода, можно целый класс переписать для каждого варианта, или же использовать простую if( BuildConfig.FLAVOR == "blablabla"){}

Comment: @Style-7, if( BuildConfig.FLAVOR == "blablabla"){}   -----  это не подойдет, если для ресурса "blablabla" нет определенного представления, (cannot find symbol)

Comment: @pavlofff, дело в том, что есть некий функционал. И надо учесть, что при необходимости можно было этот функционал реализовать под разный дизайн. Пример, 1 активность и 2 разных макета, для flavor(1) - 1 макет, для flavor(2) - 2 макет. Допустим в первом макете нет view который в свою очередь есть во 2 макете...  Я ищу правильное решение данной задачи... и как вариант рассмотрел flavor...

Comment: прежде чем продолжать искать "правильное" решение, ознакомтесь с [этим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513812/177345). короткое резюме: ваша задача не имеет правильного решения, в андроид активити, как контроллер и разметка, как отображение - одно целое (каждой разметке свой контроллер) и попытки это изменить ни к чему, кроме нелепых костылей не приведут. Если вы скажете зачем это вам, то возможно найдется и действительно правильное решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: @pavlofff, Я тоже предполагал, что возможным правильным вариантом является ваш ответ, но все-таки решил закрепиться. Спасибо за ответ !