# Абстрактный класс BaseActivity

Tags: java, android

Я хочу создать абстрактный класс `BaseActivity`, от которого бы наследовались остальные `Activity` в проекте, во всех классах Activity у меня сейчас используется `Toolbar`, поэтому хочу перенести функционал связанный с `Toolbar` в `BaseActivity`. Не знаю, как это правильно сделать.

Делаю так, класс `BaseActivity`:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // NullPointerException
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_24dp);
    }

    public void addToolbarTitle(String titleName){
        toolbar.setTitle(titleName);
    };
}
```

Потом наследуюсь обычной `Activity` от `BaseActivity`:

```
public class ConversationActivity extends BaseActivity  {

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversation);
}

}
```

Получаю `NullPointerException` в `BaseActivity`, как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

До вызова `setContentView()` представления не существует и вызов `findViewById(R.id.toolbar)` вернёт `null`. Вынесите код установки toolbar'а в отдельный метод в `BaseActivity` и вызывайте его в `onCreate()` дочерних классов после установки макета.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;

    protected void setToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_24dp);
    }

    public void addToolbarTitle(String titleName){
        toolbar.setTitle(titleName);
    };
}

public class ConversationActivity extends BaseActivity  {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversation);
        setToolbar();
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то, что нужно!